# Error: readline on closed filehandle using Perl

Tags: file, perl, filereader, file-handling, file-writing

```
!/usr/bin/perl
use Cwd;
use warnings;

open($fh,'<', "clinical.txt");
$line = <$fh>;

while($line = <$fh>)
{   
    
    my @fields2 =split(" ",$line);
    push(@id,$fields2[1]);

    push(@status,$fields2[3]);
    }
@flow = grep { -d } glob "*"; 
$arrSize = @flow;
for ($p = 0; $p < $arrSize; $p++)
{

    @files=<$flow[$p]/*.maf>;
    print $flow[$p],"\n";
    
    foreach $file(@files)
    {
        print $file,"\n";
        open(x,$file);
        %hash={};
        %tested={};
        %Mut_Count={};
        $hyper=0;
        $line = <x>;
        $line = <x>;
        $line = <x>;
        $line = <x>;
        $line = <x>;
        $line = <x>;
        while($line = <x>)
        {
            @temp=split("\t",$line);
            $key=$temp[4]."_".$temp[5]."_".$temp[6]."_".$temp[10]."_".$temp[11]."_".$temp[12]."_".$temp[15];
            push @{$hash{$key}}, "0";
            push @{$Mut_Count{$temp[15]}}, "0";
        }
        
        @nm=split(/\./,$file);
        open(x,$file);
        open(Out1,">Results/".$nm[1]."_Hyper.txt");
        $line = <x>;
        $line = <x>;
        $line = <x>;
        $line = <x>;
        $line = <x>;
        @temp=split(" ",$line);
        @temp2=split(",",$temp[1]);
        print Out1 "Gene\tMutation\tType\tdbSNP\tStatus\tPolyphen\tSift";
        for($j=0;$j<scalar(@id);$j++){
        my @M=split('-', $id[$j]);
        for($i=0;$i<scalar(@temp2);$i++)
        {
        my @N=split('-', $temp2[$i]);
            if(scalar(@{$Mut_Count{$temp2[$i]}})>499 && $M[0] eq $N[0] && $M[1] eq $N[1] && $M[2] eq $N[2] && $status[$j] eq 'MSS')
            {
                print Out1 "\t",$temp2[$i];
                $hyper++;
            }
        }
}
        $line = <x>;
        while($line = <x>)
        {
            $hy=0;
            @temp=split("\t",$line);
            $key=$temp[4]."_".$temp[5]."_".$temp[6]."_".$temp[10]."_".$temp[11]."_".$temp[12];
            if(!exists $tested{$key})
            {
                push @{$tested{$key}}, "0";
                print Out1 "\n",$temp[0],"\t",$key,"\t",$temp[8],"\t",$temp[13],"\t",$temp[25],"\t",$temp[72],"\t",$temp[73];
                
        for($i=0;$i<scalar(@temp2);$i++)
        {

                
                    $key=$temp[4]."_".$temp[5]."_".$temp[6]."_".$temp[10]."_".$temp[11]."_".$temp[12]."_".$temp2[$i];
                    
                    my @L=split('-', $temp2[$i]);
                    for($j=0;$j<scalar(@id);$j++){
        my @O=split('-', $id[$j]);
                    if(scalar(@{$Mut_Count{$temp2[$i]}})>499 && $L[0] eq $O[0] && $L[1] eq $O[1] && $L[2] eq $O[2] && $status[$j] eq 'MSS')
                    {
                        if(exists $hash{$key})
                        {
                            print Out1 "\t1";
                            $hy++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            print Out1 "\t0";
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
        }
        open(Out3,">Results/".$nm[1]."_Summary.txt");
        print Out3 "Hypermutated\t$hyper\n";
    }
}
```

`$line = <$fh>; while($line = <$fh>)`
these lines are showing readline() on closed filehandle $fh

`%hash={}; %tested={}; %Mut_Count={};`
on these three lines it says Reference found where even-sized list expected

.maf are basically GDC downloaded files with bit modified header according to our need with unique TCGA IDs.
Whereas, Clinical Info is file contaning TCGA IDs, its source and MSI_Status that tells us whether it is MSI-L, MSI-H or MSS.
I'm reading multiple .maf files and comparing it with clinical_info file
and if the if condition is satisfied that I want it to generate mastertable(write a file)
I'm doing it in windows. Kindly, help me resolve this, Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Could you please show us the entire error message and also it would be great to include the input files which you're trying to read and expected results(output) as well.

Comment: Re: _`these lines are showing readline() on closed filehandle $fh`_ -- then it appears that the file wasn't opened.  One always wants to check that anyway so make it `open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";` (name that `my $file = 'clinical.txt';` first).  Then if the file can't be opened it will print the reason

Comment: Also, you *must* always have `use warnings;` (adding which requires no changes to the rest of the code), and `use strict;` (for which you need to declare with `my` all variables as they are introduced)

Comment: Has the question changed? This issue was about a `readline on a closed filehandle` a while ago. Not is is something different. Please post links to the input files you are using -- there is not enough context to fault find you issue by just looking at the code. Ideally keep the input file ssmall.

Comment: yes i have reolved that

Comment: kindly help me resolve this one

Comment: You need to supply us with some input data that triggers the issue.  We need to reproduce the issue  to understand the rppt-cause.

Comment: @AqsaArshad.: I have rolled your question back to the original one. If you have solved this question please post a solution and accept it. But if you have a new problem then please post it as a new, separate question.

Comment: You should make sure your open() succeeds before you read from a file handle. Something like `open ( ... ) or die "Open failed: $!";`

Answer (score 1):

Answer to

```
%hash={}; %tested={}; %Mut_Count={}; on these three lines it says Reference found where even-sized list expected
```

You can get rid of the errors by getting rid of these three lines, though if you accept (please!) the `use strict;` recommendation you will need to replace them with `my %hash;` and so forth.

Under Perl, hashes (and arrays) do not need to be initialized. If you wish to initialize one, you assign it another array, or a list, or another hash. The length of the initializer must be even, since it is interpreted as key/value pairs. Your code supplied a hash reference, which will **not** be expanded by Perl to an empty hash. Hence the error.

If it makes you nervous not to initialize the hash, you can say `my %hash = ();`.

On the other hand, if you intend to use a scalar as a hash reference, you will need to initialize it. This is where you use the curly brackets, which (among other things) are a hash constructor which returns a reference to the constructed hash. So:

```
my $hash = {};
$hash->{$key} = $value;
...
```

Comment: push @{$hash{$key}}, "0";
in this line value passed should be array not a hash element.

Comment: `@{$hash{$key}}` **is** an array. If element `$hash{$key}` does not exist, it will be autovivified as an array reference, and `"0"` will be pushed onto it.